# Behavior of std.variant with large types

Tags: d, variant

According to the [docs](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html#.Variant):

> You may want to use VariantN directly with a different maximum size [from Variant] either for storing larger types, or for saving memory.

I assumed this meant that a `Variant` would not accept large structs, yet the following passes:

```
struct S {
  long[2048] vals;
}

static assert(Variant.allowed!S);
```

So what exactly happens when I stick a large type like `S` in a standard `Variant`?
Does the `S` automatically get boxed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `allowed` only checks the list of types, not the size.

But with a large thing, it gets copied into a heap thing: line 627 of variant.d's source code show it. If the size fits in the store, it is stored right here. Otherwise, a heap copy is created and a pointer to that is stored.

So yeah, it is basically boxed as needed.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear from the docs, but the source confirms it.

Comment: I have created a pull request for the Variant documentation to document this behaviour: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/3180